# Why doesn't it stop?

Tags: prolog

If I have the following rule:

```
test(X, Y, abc) :- X=='true' ; Y =='true'.
```

and I make a query such as: `test(true, true, X).`

Why would it output `X = abc ?` twice?

```
| ?- test(true, true, X).
X = abc ? n
X = abc ? n
no
```

Shouldn't it 'answer' only once?

Shouldn't it find that X == true and then stop because if only one condition is true then the whole condition is true?

Comment: `test(true, true, abc)` succeeds twice because your rule says it is true if `X == true` OR if `Y == true`. So it succeeds in two different ways. Prolog will show you all of the solutions.

Comment: ... and you can always write `true` in place of `'true'`

Answer (score 1):

This happens because Prolog will try to find you all of the possible solutions, and will follow all possible paths to do so. You give two possible paths to truthiness, so it will follow them both and show you both results.